# Refresh Jqgrid in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid

I have jqgrid that need to refresh data onchange event, i create table with js and make object of jqgrid like this:

```
$('<table id="list2"></table>' +
    '<div id="gridpager"></div>').appendTo('#topics');
grid = jQuery("#list2");
```

after this, I have an ajax function to get data from the database and I put jqgrid on the success method. here is the code.

```
function getReport(start_date,end_date) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "logics/inventory_reports",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            type: "getTrailBalance_report",
            start_date: start_date,
            end_date: end_date,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            let dt = JSON.parse(data);
            debugger;
            grid.jqGrid({
                datastr: dt.records,
                datatype: "jsonstring",
                height: "auto",
                loadui: "disable",
                pgbuttons : false,
                pginput : false,
                colNames: [/*"id",*/"Items","Debit", "Credit"],
                colModel: [
                    //{name: "id",width:1, hidden:true, key:true},
                    {name: "name", width:250, resizable: false,sortable: false},
                    {name: "debit",width:150,sortable: false},
                    {name: "credit",width:150,sortable: false}
                ],
                treeGrid: true,
                pager : '#gridpager',
                caption: "Trail Balance Report",
                ExpandColumn: "elementName",
                autowidth: true,

                rowNum: 10000,
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "response"
                }
            }).navGrid('#gridpager',{
                view:true,
                del:false,
                search: false,
                autoRefresh: true,
            });
            jQuery("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid");

        }
    });
}
```

and here is my dropdown onchange event.

```
<select name="time_period" id="time_period" class="form-control" onchange="getTimePeriod()">
                        <option value="0">--Select Time Period--</option>
                        <option value="cDay">Current Day</option>
                        <option value="lDay">Last Day</option>
                        <option value="cWeek">Current Week</option>
                        <option value="lWeek">Last Week</option>
                        <option value="cMonth">Current Month</option>
                        <option value="lMonth">Last Month</option>
                        <option value="cYear">Current Year</option>
                        <option value="lYear">Last Year</option>
                    </select>
```

here is the code of getTimePeriod() method from where I call the getReport method with passing parameters.

function getTimePeriod() {

```
    let timePeriod = $("#time_period").val();
    let periodDate = new Date();
    let date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
    let message = "";
    let FYear;
    let start_date = new Date();
    debugger;
    switch (timePeriod) {

        case 'cDay':
            periodDate = new Date();
            message = 'Current Day';
            break;

        case 'lDay':
            //periodDate = new Date;
            start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() - 1);
            periodDate.setDate(periodDate.getDate() - 1);
            // periodDate = periodDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
            message = 'Last Day';
            break;

        case 'cWeek':
            //periodDate = new Date;
            start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() - (start_date.getDay() + 6) % 7); // Starting date of week
            periodDate.setDate(periodDate.getDate() - (periodDate.getDay() - 7) % 7); // Ending date of Week
            message = 'Current Week';
            break;

        case 'lWeek':
            start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() - (start_date.getDay() + 6) % 7);// Starting date.
            start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() - 7);
            periodDate.setDate(periodDate.getDate() - (periodDate.getDay() -  7) % 7); // Ending date.
            periodDate.setDate(periodDate.getDate() - 7);
            message = 'Last Week';
            break;

        case 'cMonth':
            start_date = new Date(y, m, 1); // Starting date of this month.
            periodDate = new Date(y, m + 1, 0); // Ending date of this month.
            message = 'Current Month';
            break;

        case 'lMonth':
            start_date = new Date(y, m - 1, 1); // Starting date of the previous Month.
            periodDate = new Date(y, m, 0); // Ending date of the previous Month.
            message = 'Last Month';
            break;

        case 'cYear':
            FYear = getFinancialYearsLastMonth();
            start_date = new Date(y, FYear, 1); // Starting date of this Financial Year.
            periodDate = new Date(y +1, FYear, 0); /*#### second value tells the month number ######*/ // Ending Date.
            message = 'Current Year';
            break;

        case 'lYear':
            FYear = getFinancialYearsLastMonth();
            start_date = new Date(y - 1, FYear, 1); // Starting date of previous Financial Year.
            periodDate = new Date(y, FYear, 0); /*#### second value tells the month number ######*/ // Ending Date
            message = 'Last Year';
            break;

    }

    // periodDate = periodDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    document.getElementById("showDate").innerHTML = getDateInFormat(periodDate);
    getReport(ReFormateDate(start_date),ReFormateDate(periodDate));

}
```

avoid the rest code from getTimePeriod method just see the calling of getReport.

I put debugger and test that every time the data is updated but jqgrid is not refreshing the data. I tried but like jQuery("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid"); and .navGrid('#gridpager',{
view:true,
del:false,
search: false,
autoRefresh: true,
}); but no effected. Can you help me out with this issue, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your realization you call the jqGrid (your function getReport) every time when you do change - the reason for not updating the grid is that it is already created.

When the grid instance is created any call to it does nothing.
I see two easy solutions

1. In your case you can simple destroy the grid before it is created - check the docs depending on which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid or free-jqGrid. - and then call the jqGrid instance.
2. When you create the grid for the first time, mark that it is created and after the first call in your success function do (this is just not tested code)

- 

```
success: function (data) {
    let dt = JSON.parse(data);
    if (grid_is_created) {
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{ data: dt.records}).trigger("reloadGrid");
    } else {
        grid.jqGrid({...});
        grid_is_created= true;
    }
```

Comment: I tried the first solution and when I put grid.jqGrid("GridUnload"); method it loads first time perfectly but when at 2nd time it removes the grid

Comment: and for 2nd solution, it happens the same as I said in my Question. it loads the first time but on change, it doesn't change the record.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you realize the first option? I recommend you to put gridUnload before the ajax call and not within success function. It seems you use free-jqGrid, since the call of gridUnload in Guriddo is quite different. In previous release this method has problems, so I recommend you to put it before ajax and better to switch to the supported Guriddo jqGrid. free-jqGrid is dead from 3 years.

Comment: Same issue on calling gridUnload before ajax.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: jqGrid  version : 4.6.0

Comment: This version is about 8 years old and is no more supported. Not sure if we can prepare a demo.  One more comment - your reloading of  the grid in your report function us useless and will cause more problems than benefits.